# hibernate criteria on date returns empty result

Tags: java, hibernate, date, criteria, restrictions

In DB2 I have dates in format 
    2013-06-27-10.20.23.000000
I would like to retrieve all the people born on **27-06**.

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM");
String myDate = "27-06";
Date date = formatter.parse(myDate);
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(PersonalDetails.class);
Criterion restrictDate = Restrictions.like("PersonalDetails",date);
```

but it brings me empty result:

Answer (score 0):

I have tried

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM");
String myDate = "27-06";
Date date = formatter.parse(myDate);
System.out.println(date);
```

result was Sat Jun 27 00:00:00 EET 1970.